# Synology DSM (Unix) - Cannot SSH with another user

Tags: ssh, synology

On my Synology (DSM 6.2.2-24922), I have 3 users:

- `admin` (disabled ssh and login)
- `user1` (my new admin user, recommanded by Synology)
- `user2` (not admin)

I can connect throw ssh with `user1` but not with `user2`.

I edited `/etc/passwd` to replace `/sbin/nologin`:

```
user1:x:1026:100:Administrator:/var/services/homes/user1:/bin/sh
user2:x:1035:100::/var/services/homes/user2:/bin/sh
```

I can `su` user2 from `user1` and `ls` its home directory:

```sh
sudo su - user2
```

But ssh command always returns `Permission denied`:

```
user2@my.domain.com's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to my.domain.com ([123.123.123.123]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to my.domain.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2204, received 2744 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 23710.3, received 29519.5
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log in via `ssh`, the user must be in the "administrators" group. If you look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the Synology you will see an `AllowGroups` line that sets up this restriction. If you put `user2` into the `administrators` group, they will be able to log in with `ssh`. Putting a user into the `administrators` group will automatically change their shell (the last field on their line in `/etc/passwd`) from `/sbin/no login` to `/bin/bash`.

My Synology sshd configuration allows a second group, "ssh_users", but I have not tested that at all.

If you play around with this, be aware that manual changes to user properties in files like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are often undone if you modify the user in DSM, and sometimes if you make apparently unrelated changes in DSM. Sometimes an upgrade will undo manual changes too.

Comment: Thanks! I update my user to put him in `administrator` group and it's worked.

For information, before the last update (< 6.2.2-24922) I could connect with `user2` in ssh (and the update reset all my settings once more). But I didn't remember (and I'm not sure) that I had to put him in admin group ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I suppose it should be said that putting someone in the administrators group does make them an administrator... so they are not really an ordinary user any more. They will have privileges on your NAS that you may not want them to have. If you have time to do so, maybe investigate the ssh_users idea...

Comment: Yes I will use a group, especially that I created user2 not to be admin :) For now I neither have ssh group nor Allowgroups, so I have to create a new group and add it to ssh config.

Comment: I tried a lot, but it still doesent work to enable a non admin-group user to ssh connect, i edited the user in passwd to /bin/sh, restarted the ssh-shell via synoservice --restart, sshd_config doesent contain a allowgroups.

Comment: @Kuronashi Sorry, I cannot help you I let my user in administrator 

Comment: One more thing I just discovered: Creating a new user and adding him to the administrator group still shows `/sbin/nologin` as his shell using `synouser --get YOUR_USER`. This only works after the user has logged into the NAS via the Web-Interface at least once. That step done, everything works as expected. Hope that helps.